# How to organize my views with posts on different columns and lines

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I am  implementing a website using Ruby on rails, and bootstrap.
I have several post (small text with picture) for an user for example and I want to print them on the screen.
I use will_paginate to make them appear on different pages. But my problem is when I want to organize them on the page, for the moment i use

so my page looks like :

```
  User : post
  User : post
  User : post
      ...
```

But I would like to have :

```
User : post        User : post      User : post
User : post        User : post      User : post
User : post        User : post      User : post
                        ....
```

**EDIT**
My actual views :

**_feed.html.erb**

```
<% if @feed_items.any? %>
  <ol class="microposts">
    <%= render partial: 'shared/feed_item', collection: @feed_items %>
  </ol>
  <%= will_paginate @feed_items %>
<% end %>
```

**_feed_item.html.erb**

```
<li id="<%= feed_item.id %>">
  <%= link_to gravatar_for(feed_item.user), feed_item.user %>
  <span class="user">
    <%= link_to feed_item.user.name, feed_item.user %>
  </span>
  <span class="photo">
    <% if feed_item.image? %>
    <%= image_tag feed_item.image.url %>
    <% end %>
  </span>
  <span class="timestamp">
    Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(feed_item.created_at) %> ago.
  </span>
  <% if current_user?(feed_item.user) %>
  <%= link_to "delete", feed_item, method: :delete,
  data: { confirm: "You sure?" }%>
  <% end %>
</li>
```

**Final edit : result**

```
<% if @feed_items.any? %>
  <% @feed_items.each_slice(3) do |slice| %>
    <% slice.each do |photo| %>
    <ol class="microposts">
      <%= render partial: 'shared/feed_item', collection: @feed_items %>
    </ol>
    <%end%>
  <% end %>
  <%= will_paginate @feed_items %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: please show your views code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this just a little while ago actually. The way I ended up doing it was using the `each_slice` method. It's really handy! It would look something like:

```
<% if @feed_items.any? %>
  <% @feed_items.each_slice(3) do |feed_items_slice| %>
    <ol class="microposts">
      <%= render partial: 'shared/feed_item', collection: feed_items_slice %>
    </ol>
  <% end %>
  <%= will_paginate @feed_items %>
<% end %>
```

Obviously the styles will have to change. I would suggest floating the `li` tags to the left, and then making the `ol` tag clear:both to make sure it gets put on a new line.

Comment: Perfect thank you ! I edit my own post to show how is my code now :) !